# Regular expression for obtaining a vowel occurrence in Java?

Tags: java, regex, text

For coding an ID generator, I got to obtain the first vowel appearance ignoring first letter in a lastname.

I coded:

```
public static Character primeraVocal(String apellido) {

    for (Character c : apellido.toUpperCase().substring(1).toCharArray()) {
        if (c.equals('A') || c.equals('E') || c.equals('I') || c.equals('O') || c.equals('U'))
            return c;
    }

    return '!';
}
```

However I know this would be sort of one line of code using a regex. How would it look like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you want to ignore the first letter, this code will help you get there.

```
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[\\w]([aeiouâãäåæçèéêëìíîïðñòóôõøùúûü])", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("Aguilar");
    if (matcher.find()) {
        return String.valueOf(matcher.group(1));
    }
```

You can also use this method in order to normalize your returned `String`. So when you get an accented vowel, you can use the normalized value to create your ID....

```
public static String unAccent(String s) {
    //http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0456.html
    String temp = Normalizer.normalize(s, Normalizer.Form.NFD);
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\p{InCombiningDiacriticalMarks}+");
    return pattern.matcher(temp).replaceAll("");
}
```

Please see the working example here... https://ideone.com/gaGbtF

Comment: Can you explain `[\\w]` and `.group` method?

Comment: Hello @diegoaguilar, the `\w` will match any word character and the group, will give you the match for the parenthesis group in the regular expression. For example on this case group 1 is whatever matches what's inside the only parenthesis on the `regex`.

Comment: I am editing the answer so it will also work with Spanish accented vowels.

Comment: Solving out accented vowels will make it, thanks! I asked about `[\\w]` because it has two `\\`

Comment: +1 for noticing the ignore-first-letter requirement. But your regex is only finding vowels that happen to be the *second character*.

Comment: @aliteralmind oh no. If you go to http://regex101.com/r/jM7dD5 you will see the working regular expression.

Comment: Oh! You're not anchoring with a word boundary. Excellent.

Comment: @diegoaguilar Please check the edited answer for the method that will normalize any accented vowels.

Comment: I did, it's so great. Thanks Dominican :P

Comment: My answer does the same thing with a less elegant regex: It anchors to the start of the word. Knowing there's only one search per line makes the word-boundary un-needed. Smart.

Comment: @GarisMSuero so is suggested to use normalize method at last in order to have a a normalized string, over either lastname, city, name, etc ... right?

Comment: That's entirely up to you @diegoaguilar and your broader app design. The desired application will support everything. Special characters are not recommended for primary keys though.

Comment: Sure, get it. What I asked, first method only finds matches, second one will normalize. About group, it refers about what's inside the `()` within the regex, I understand

Answer (score 3):

Use `if (new String(c).matches("[AEIOUaeiou]"))` and you can also drop the upper case conversion function `toUpperCase`

`[]` is used to denote characters in range. Regular expressions can impact performance, so do use then carefully.

If I were you I'd use

```
switch (c){
    case 'A': case 'E': case 'I': case 'O': case 'U':
        /*vowel*/
        break;
    default:
        /*not a vowel*/
        break;
}
```

Which is both fast (switching on `char` is fast) and clear.

Comment: This wouldn't compile. There is no `matches()` method in `Character` class.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following (simplified) `Pattern`:

```
String input = "Gonzalez";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[aeiouy]", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
Matcher m = p.matcher(input);
if (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(String.format("First vowel: %s", m.group()));
}
else {
    System.out.println("No vowels in input.");
}
```

**Output**

```
First vowel: o
```

**Note**

This is a simplistic solution that won't work with accented vowels.

Comment: +1; but note that the answerer has put in `y`; at odds with the OP.

Comment: You've already given up your performance rights in using a regular expression.

Comment: @Bathsheba about `y`: it is a vowel though :) About performance, agreed although not sure there is much performance to discuss in this case.

Comment: @diegoaguilar as long as you don't iterate compiling of `Pattern`, you should be totally ok with such a short input.

Comment: I didn't think about accented vowels, would it be any alternative to *standarize* inputs to non accented?

Comment: @diegoaguilar you can use a [Normalizer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/Normalizer.html) for that. But it does impact on the text being parsed. An ugly solution would be to add the most commonly accented characters in the [aei...] group. I think acute accents would be sufficient for Spanish surnames (diaeresis is not common in surnames). Beware Catalan and other regional surnames though:)

Answer (score 1):

*UPDATE: I didn't notice the "not first character" requirement. Updated to find the first vowel AFTER the first letter. A much more interesting regex.  `:)`*

I don't know about a one-liner, but this works and is pretty concise. Since it compiles the pattern and creates the matcher only once, I think it's as fast and efficient as you're going get with regular expressions:

```
   import  java.util.regex.Matcher;
   import  java.util.regex.Pattern;
public class PrimevaVocal  {

   //"": Unused to-search string so the matcher can be reset (and reused).
   private static final Matcher MTCHR_VOWEL = Pattern.compile(
      "\\b\\w[^aeiou]*([aeiou])",
      Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE).matcher("");

      //Alternate and more elegant regex, thanks 
      //to @GarisMSuero: "[\\w]([aeiou])"

   public static final void main(String[] ignored)  {
      System.out.println(primevaVocal("Speller"));
      System.out.println(primevaVocal("Estinshtien"));
      System.out.println(primevaVocal("Xyz"));
   }
   public static final Character primevaVocal(String to_search)  {
      return  (!MTCHR_VOWEL.reset(to_search).find()  ? '!'
        :  MTCHR_VOWEL.group(1).charAt(0));
   }
}
```

Output:

```
[C:\java_code\]java PrimevaVocal
e
i
!
```

Comment: Updated to find the vowel *after* the first character, as is the OP's requirements.

Comment: By golly, I did squeeze it down to one line (post initialization of the Pattern)  :)